# Calling a function from a map of pointers to functions having a variable number arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following program. Is there a way to implement the `call()` function without all the `if` statements in the body? Feel free to change the type of the map to find a solution. `call()` should also throw an exception in case of bad number of arguments. The interface of `call()` can be changed, but the name of the function, the pointer to the array of arguments and the number of arguments are known at runtime only.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef double(*PF1)(double);
typedef double(*PF2)(double, double);
typedef double(*PF3)(double, double, double);

map<string, boost::any> m = {
    {"sin", static_cast<PF1> (std::sin)},
    {"pow", static_cast<PF2> (std::pow)}
    // other 
};

double call(string name, double* args, int nargs) {
    if (name == "sin" && nargs == 1)
        return boost::any_cast<PF1>(m[name])(args[0]);
    else if (name == "pow" && nargs == 2)
        return boost::any_cast<PF2>(m[name])(args[0], args[1]);
    // etc...
}

int main() {
    double n[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int narg1 = 1, narg2 = 2; // known at runtime
    double r = call("sin", n, narg1);
    r = call("pow", n, narg2);
}
```

Comment: Variadic templates may help.

Comment: Yes, I am asking how they can help...

Comment: Give them a try and find out?!

Comment: A `std::function` object's function call operator can take any number of arguments and simply discards the additional ones IIRC.

Comment: Probably I already tried and didn't find out anything useful?

Comment: The interface of `call` is fixed? I.e. you can't replace it with a variadic template like `template<class... Args> double call(string name, Args&&... args);`?

Comment: I can change the interface of call(), but the pointer to the arguments and the number of arguments is known at runtime

Comment: Show us HOW did you try variable templates?

Comment: Question: *Why?* I have the feeling that there is a larger problem for which there might be different solutions than the one for which you are asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's *another* way to do it. Essentially, it uses the OP's code (dispatching via `if`s), so it doesn't need a map or type erasure. However, it requires a tail-recurring sequence of `if`-`else`s instead of a lookup in a map. So the lookup is slower, but it doesn't need indirections.

```
// a helper type to generate and deduce a sequence of integers
template<int...> struct seq {};
template<int N, int... Is> struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template<int... Is> struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...> {};


#include <string>
#include <cassert>

template<class T, T t>
struct c_fptr;

template<class... Args, double(*fptr)(Args...)>
struct c_fptr<double(*)(Args...), fptr>
{
    std::string name;

    double operator()(double* argv, int argc) const
    {
        assert(argc == sizeof...(Args));
        return dispatch(argv, gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)>{});
    }

    template<int... Is>
    double dispatch(double* argv, seq<Is...>) const
    {
        return fptr(argv[Is]...);
    }
};
```

Similarly to my type-erasure approach, we use a template parameter to store the function pointer. The objects of this type will be stored in a `tuple`

```
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

typedef double(*PF1)(double);
typedef double(*PF2)(double, double);
typedef double(*PF3)(double, double, double);

#include <tuple>

auto x = std::make_tuple(
      c_fptr<PF1, std::sin>{"sin"}
    , c_fptr<PF2, std::pow>{"pow"}
);
```

This tuple now is used in a recursive function call, where each step checks if the name of one of the tuple elements matches the passed string:

```
// end recursion
double call_recurse(std::string const& name, double* argv, int argc)
{
    throw std::invalid_argument("name not found");
}

template<class T, class... TT>
double call_recurse(std::string const& name, double* argv, int argc,
                    T const& l, TT const&... rest)
{
    if(name == l.name)
    {
        return l(argv, argc);
    }else
    {
        return call_recurse(name, argv, argc, rest...);
    }
}

template<int... Is>
double call_dispatch(std::string const& name, double* argv, int argc, seq<Is...>)
{
    return call_recurse(name, argv, argc, std::get<Is>(x)...);
}

double call(std::string const& name, double* argv, int argc)
{
    return call_dispatch(name, argv, argc,
                         gen_seq<std::tuple_size<decltype(x)>::value>{});
}
```

Comment: I bet you can also sort the tuple elements at compile-time, and maybe build a compile-time binary search inside the recursion o.O

Comment: This is indeed another great solution. I'll go with this one. Thanks. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it: Use inheritance for type erase. This is a minimal example that stores a function pointer as a non-type template argument.

Another way is to use `std::function`, which discards additional arguments IIRC.

```
struct var_double_func_base
{
    virtual ~var_double_func_base() {}
    virtual double operator()(double*, int) = 0;
};


// a helper type to generate and deduce a sequence of integers
template<int...> struct seq {};
template<int N, int... Is> struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template<int... Is> struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...> {};


#include <cassert>

// a delegate-like class, storing the function to call as a non-type template
// parameter
template<class T, T t>
struct var_double_fptr;

template<class... Args, double(*fptr)(Args...)>
struct var_double_fptr<double(*)(Args...), fptr>
    : var_double_func_base
{
    virtual double operator()(double* argv, int argc)
    {
        assert(argc == sizeof...(Args));
        return dispatch(argv, gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)>{});
    }

    template<int... Is>
    double dispatch(double* argv, seq<Is...>)
    {
        return fptr(argv[Is]...);
    }
};
```

Usage example: (Note -- prefer `unique_ptr`, but that doesn't work for uniform init of the map.)

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

typedef double(*PF1)(double);
typedef double(*PF2)(double, double);
typedef double(*PF3)(double, double, double);

std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<var_double_func_base>> m = {
    {"sin", std::make_shared<var_double_fptr<PF1, std::sin>>()},
    {"pow", std::make_shared<var_double_fptr<PF2, std::pow>>()}
    // other 
};

double call(std::string name, double* argv, int argc)
{
    auto i = m.find(name);
    assert(i != m.end());
    return (*(i->second))(argv, argc);
}

int main() {
    double n[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int narg1 = 1, narg2 = 2; // known at runtime
    double r = call("sin", n, narg1);
    r = call("pow", n, narg2);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. This works and also teached me how to generate a sequence of integers via variadic templates, which is the point where I was stuck at. +1 . I am going to analyze your second answer and choose the best one. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin Note we'll get `std::integer_sequence`, `std::make_integer_sequence` etc. in C++1y