# SFINAE on pointers to overloaded functions

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following program. I use `h()` as an helper to resolve ambiguities with pointers to overloaded functions from cmath:

```
#include <cmath>

typedef double(*PF1)(double);
typedef double(*PF2)(double, double);
typedef double(*PF3)(double, double, double);
// etc...

auto h(PF1 p) -> decltype(p) {return p;}
auto h(PF2 p) -> decltype(p) {return p;}
auto h(PF3 p) -> decltype(p) {return p;}

int f(int) {return 0;}; // my math function

int main() {
    //auto s_ = std::sin; // won't work as std::sin is overloaded
    auto s = h(std::sin); // works, type of s is a double(*)(double)
    auto p = h(std::pow); // OK.
    // auto my_aim = h(f); // my aim is to make h() work with f too
}
```

Is there a smarter or more generic helper to deduct the type of a pointer to (a possibily) overloaded function given a pointer to the function itself, so that the deduction would "prefer" either the overload with only double types involved (as return type and arguments) if available, or one of other overloads otherwise.

Comment: type traits? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types  Consider removing the pointer, and observing the type: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_pointer

Comment: Yes, can you show me how to  use type traits?

Comment: Actually, If you want to store a function, take a look at std::function http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: @Martin This looks similar to [Calling a function from a map of pointers to functions having a variable number arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049681/calling-a-function-from-a-map-of-pointers-to-functions-having-a-variable-number?rq=1)

Comment: @remyabel that's my previous question :) but this is another matter which will be integrated with that answer

Comment: It seems you need some total or partial ordering of the overloads ("or one of other overloads otherwise"). Sure you can write a helper that selects an overload that only has double parameters, but what to do otherwise? What should be the ordering relation?

Comment: Hello @dyp, fortunately you are here :) Do you remember my previous question about calling a function from a map of pointers? Well actually the goal is to build the map or the tuple there without having to specify the types PF1, PF2, PFn... it would be great if these types could be deduced from the function pointer itself (giving higher precedence to the overloads having doubles involved). I hope it's clear. Probably I should write another question.

Comment: @Martin I recognized the code before I saw the name ;) Well, imagine an overload set `double foo(int); int foo(double);` which one should be chosen? If such things are not possible in your domain, what about `int bar(int); int bar(float);` or `int bar(double); int bar(double, double);`? I think you need to impose some restrictions on the possible overloads and define some kind of ordering relation.

Comment: @dyp if there's "double bar(double)" or "double foo(double)", with all the types being double, then they will be choosen, otherwise one of the other overloads with no preferred preference (SFINAE?). I don't know if it's mandaroty to define an order for all the possible overloads. For my aim if there's one function having all the types as double, then this should be picked up, otherwise any other overload is fine.

Comment: @Martin Well the compiler has to select one of the overloads, and it has to do it *deterministically*. So there needs to be an algorithm that selects one of the overloads. Since function pointers aren't implicitly converted to other function pointers, and selection from an overload set can only be done via an exact match, I don't think there *is* already such an algorithm, so we'll need to define one. Some parts can be deduced from a function name naming an overload set, but if deduction is ambiguous, it fails.

Comment: Well for now consider functions from cmath. They at least have an overload with double as return type and arguments. Now consider my helper h() above. Is there a way to make it a template? I want to at least make the code shorter. Now I can write: auto x = std::make_tuple(
      c_fptr<decltype(h(std::sin)), std::sin>{"sin"}
    , c_fptr<decltype(h(std::pow)), std::pow>{"pow"}
);  Which is a small improvement compared to having to specify PF1, PF2, PF3. Probably I can write a macro to avoid to specify the function pointer twice in the map as well.

Comment: Something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c7192d288828ab4) might work, but unfortunately it doesn't for libstdc++'s `<cmath>` overloads (not sure why). Note that deduction happens before substitution, so SFINAE can't be applied to select an overload (at least, not directly).

Answer (score 3):

The following may help:

```
constexpr auto h(double(*p)(double)) -> decltype(p) {return p;}
constexpr auto h(double(*p)(double, double)) -> decltype(p) {return p;}
constexpr auto h(double(*p)(double, double, double)) -> decltype(p) {return p;}

template <typename Return, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto h(Return (*p)(Args...)) -> decltype(p) {return p;}

int f(int) {return 0;}; // my math function

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //auto s_ = std::sin; // won't work as std::sin is overloaded
    auto s = h(std::sin); // works, type of s is a double(*)(double)
    auto p = h(std::pow); // OK.
    auto my_aim = h(f); // works too

    return 0;
}
```

As long as `h` arguments is in one provided (`double(*p)(double..)`) or there is no overload (as for `f`) (so template can deduce its type).

**EDIT**

Add a more generic class to handle that:

```
template<typename Sign, typename ... Signs>
struct identity : identity<Signs...>
{
    using identity<Signs...>::h;
    static constexpr auto h(Sign p) -> decltype(p) {return p;}
};

template<typename Sign>
struct identity<Sign>
{
    static constexpr auto h(Sign p) -> decltype(p) {return p;}

    template <typename T>
    static constexpr auto h(T p) -> decltype(p) {return p;}
};
```

Let's use it with your example:

```
typedef identity<double(*)(double),
                 double(*)(double, double),
                 double(*)(double, double, double)> MyIdentity;

int f(int) {return 0;}; // my math function

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto s = MyIdentity::h(std::sin); // works : double(*)(double)
    auto p = MyIdentity::h(pow);      // works : double(*)(double, double)
    auto my_aim = MyIdentity::h(f);   // works : (int)(*)(int)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can also produce the list of overloads `h` automatically (via metaprogramming), though the syntax for calling it will we slightly different (`h` will need to be a static member function of a class template).

Comment: @dyp: added an example of your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I can get to what you are trying to do:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>

template<typename R, typename ...A>
auto h(R f(A...)) -> std::function<R(A...)>
{
    return std::function<R(A...)>(f);
}

int main() {

    auto s = h<double, double>(std::sin);
    auto p = h<double, double, double>(std::pow);
}
```

You still have to specify the return type and parameters of the function you are passing in, but that is because it would be ambiguous without specifying an overload.

if you had a function whose deduced parameters would be unambiguous, it would simply be:

```
int only_one_overload(int a,  int b) {
    return a + b;
}
auto x = h(only_one_overload);
```

---

I would recomend just using function pointers though:

```
double (*s)(double) = std::sin;
double (*p)(double, double) = std::pow;
```

Comment: probably some SFINAE might be applied to avoid to specify the types at least in the case that one overload with double's only is available

Comment: That's true.  In which case, you could take the templated function above and provide an overload for doubles.

Answer (score 0):

The Boost libraries have the [Boost.Functional/OverloadedFunction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/functional/overloaded_function/doc/html/index.html) library, which is dessigned to wrap different overloads into a single function object:

```
boost::overloaded_function<
      const std::string& (const std::string&)
    , int (int)
    , double (double)
> identity(identity_s, identity_i, identity_d);

// All calls via single `identity` function.
BOOST_TEST(identity("abc") == "abc");
BOOST_TEST(identity(123) == 123);
BOOST_TEST(identity(1.23) == 1.23);
```

I think your problem could be solved easily with this library. Even if this solution does not answer your question directly, I think using `boost::overloaded_function` is a better way to bind different functions into one object and calling that different functions through one object only, which is your final goal, isn't? *(I have deduced that following your previous question)*.

Comment: The goal is to make a map of callable objects from cmath functions, i.e. std::map<std::string, boost::any> = {"sin", boost::any(h(std::sin)) /*...etc...*/};  since boost::any/compiler cannot deduct the type of std::sin without an helper since it's overloaded...I ll try boost::overload_function to see if it helps